# Creating an RPG point buy system. Why is my if condition not being met?

Tags: regex, ruby, string, if-statement, ruby-hash

I'm creating a point buy method for an RPG in which players modify their character's ability scores. My `if` condition is not being met when the input should be correct, and I can't tell why.

```
$player = {
  abils: {str: 10, con: 10, dex: 10, wis: 10, int: 10, cha: 10}
}


def abil_point_buy(x)
  points = x
  puts "<Add or subtract points from each ability (e.g. +2 STR, -1 CHA, etc.)>"
  loop do
    puts "<You have #{points} points remaining. Current ability scores:>"; print "<"
    $player[:abils].each { |abil, pts| print "#{abil.upcase}: #{pts} "}; puts ">"
    input = gets.chomp.downcase
    abil_check = $player[:abils][input.gsub("^a-z", "").to_sym]
    if abil_check && input.match?(/\d/) #checks if input contains a number and an ability score
      mod = input.gsub(/\D/, "") #determines amount to modify ability score by
      pos_or_neg = !input.include?('-') #determines if mod will be positive or negative
      $player[:abils][abil_check] + mod.to_i * (pos_or_neg ? 1 : -1) #adjusts selected ability score by mod
      pos_or_neg ? points - mod : points + mod
      break if points == 0
    else
      puts "Something is wrong with your input."
    end
  end
end
```

Would also appreciate general tips to improve my code.

Comment: What do you want to do in this line `    abil_check = $player[:abils][input.gsub("^a-z", "").to_sym]` ?

Comment: I want to define `abil_check` if `input` contains an ability score found in `$player[:abils]`.

Comment: OK, what exactly do you want to do using `gsub("^a-z", "")` ?

Comment: I want `abil_check` to only consist of the ability mentioned in `input`. (e.g.`-2 STR` should make `abil_check` equal `str`.) Then later I can do `$player[:abils][abil_check] + mod.to_i * (pos_or_neg ? 1 : -1)`.

Comment: So this gsub should filter out all non-letters, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what it should do.

Comment: It's difficult to tell you how to improve the code without a better idea how you'd use it. That also makes the question quite broad and subject to being off-topic. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an invalid pattern in `gsub`. `^a-z` is treated as "beginning of the line" followed by `a` dash and `z`. You need to replace it with a negated character class and `downcase` the string:

```
"2 STR".downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '')
# => "str"
```